# Are there more than two benefits of move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to more fully understand when to implement move semantics, and I believe it's intertwined with what the benefits are.

So far I'm aware of two.

1. Saving two likely expensive operations when moving an object (copying when the source is known to vanish soon and not be used), without move a a full copy and a full destructor would have been executed, move will save an atomic increment and decrement for atomically reference counted objects, the deep copy of bitmaps or other data structures held by pointers, or a duplication of a file handle, one of which would be closed, or any other pair of "copy" and "destruct"
2. Implement objects that can't be copied (as in duplicated), but can be moved, making sure there's ever only a single object with the same contents, yet the object can be handed off to a function. E.g. unique_ptr, or any object where copying is not possible or desired, but it needs to be created in one place but used somewhere else.

The distinction between the two is that the first deals with performance and the second with preventing semantic copying.

My question is this, are there any other uses or advantages to implementing move semantics for a class? A consideration other than performance or making sure only one location contains a live copy of the object.

Answer (score 2):

When you `move` a container in certain contexts, the pointers and references and iterators travel with it.  When you copy it, they do not.  This is neither performance, nor an unmovable object; rather, `move` offers a different set of guarantees than `copy`.

This also can hold whenever you can have anything reference-like that talks about the "inside" of a complex object.  `move` logically can make that reference travel, while `copy` may not.

Comment: It sounds very interesting, but I don't understand it at all. Can you please provide a bit more detail? An example would be nice, how to achieve it, when would you want to, and what happens when you don't ensure what ever you're talking about.

Comment: @martin do you know what a pointer, reference and iterator is?  Do you know the rules that make iteratoes into, say, a `std::set` invalid, or pointers or references to elements?  If yes, that is what I am talking about.  If no, search and read on the subject, then come back.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean (I think), and you're right, move allows things like iterators to migrate, but this would only be possible if the iterators hold no pointers to the container, otherwise move would have to iterate through iterators. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: @martin move allows pointers to elements in a set, references to elements in a set, and iterators into a set to now refer to the elements in the moved-to set when before they referred to the before-set.  Copy could nkt possibly do this.  This is unrelated to performance, or unmovable types.  And is something that move semantics can do.  Move semantics does not have to do this; see vector, where it varies (move-assign need not move iterators)

Comment: I expect vector has the variability because it stores everything together, and may resize and thus invalidating iterators. Whereas map (for example) doesn't reallocate items not touched. But my point was, that if we talk about a new container, if it had an iterator holding a pointer to the container, it couldn't retain them after move, but a pointer to an element could. And this is all due to the actual data, thus what the iterators point to, remaining intact. Whereas a deep copy would create a new set of elements, and the DTOR would kill the old ones, thus invalidating iterators. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to your points, but I think another benefit of move semantics is as a way of documenting ownership in your code. By using move you can make it clear that ownership of an object has been transferred from one place to another. This makes it easier to reason about code.

If you are trying to debug a program and understand the lifetime of an object, it is easier if there is just one path to follow. If ownership transfer is implemented as a copy you have to make sure that the lifetime of the original copy of the object has ended as well.